Use mib2c to process all OIDs in a MIB file
I need to load all OIDs from a MIB file into NET-SNMP. I couldn't find if there was a way to do this with mib2c as the command takes an OID as argument mib2c -c mib2c.conf OIDName and the documentation I followed only explains how to generate one C file at a time.
What I would like to know is whether there is a way to use an MIB file as argument, something like mib2c -c mib2c.conf MIBFile, or if a script exists to automatically generate the C code one OID at a time, or something other than mib2c that I can use to load the OIDs into NET-SNMP. Thank you
